# Convert a three digit number (eg 035) into text (eg zero three five)

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

input:**7**
output:**zero zero seven**, not seven

input:**17**
output:**zero one  seven**, not seventeen

input:**100**
output:**one zero zero**. not one hundred

I want be able to convert like the examples above, but I am not able to write the macro for the desired output. I am using Excel 2007.

Answer (score 0):

If your digits are in ColumnA starting in Row1 and you have a lookup table (say D1=0, E1=zero and so on up to D10=9 and E10=nine) then the following may suit:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(LEN(RC[-1])=1,""zero zero ""&VLOOKUP(1*RC[-1],C[2]:C[3],2,0),IF(LEN(RC[-1])=2,""zero ""&VLOOKUP(1*LEFT(RC[-1],1),C[2]:C[3],2,0)&"" ""&VLOOKUP(1*RIGHT(RC[-1],1),C[2]:C[3],2,0),VLOOKUP(1*LEFT(RC[-1],1),C[2]:C[3],2,0)&"" ""&VLOOKUP(1*MID(RC[-1],2,1),C[2]:C[3],2,0)&"" ""&VLOOKUP(1*RIGHT(RC[-1],1),C[2]:C[3],2,0)))"
    ActiveCell.Copy
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want pure VBA/no formulas or lookup tables or helper columns etc., this should do the trick.  Basically replicate the lookup table with a function that converts the specific integer values to their desired string equivalent.

```
Sub Test2()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cl As Range
    Dim clVal As String
    Dim strVal As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Set rng = Range("F1:F4")  '# Modify this line to be your range

    'Make sure they're all three digits:
    For Each cl In rng.Cells
        clVal = cl.Value
        Do While Not Len(clVal) >= 3
            clVal = "0" & clVal
        Loop
        'Now, parse the digits:
        For i = 1 To Len(clVal)
            strVal = strVal & " " & ConvertNumber(Mid(clVal, i, 1))
        Next
        strVal = Trim(strVal)
        cl.Value = strVal
        strVal = vbNullString
    Next
End Sub

Function ConvertNumber(i As Integer) As String
    Select Case i
        Case 1
            ConvertNumber = "one"
        Case 2
            ConvertNumber = "two"
        Case 3
            ConvertNumber = "three"
        Case 4
            ConvertNumber = "four"
        Case 5
            ConvertNumber = "five"
        Case 6
            ConvertNumber = "six"
        Case 7
            ConvertNumber = "seven"
        Case 8
            ConvertNumber = "eight"
        Case 9
            ConvertNumber = "nine"
        Case 0
            ConvertNumber = "zero"
    End Select
End Function
```

You could pretty easily adapt this in to a UDF that you could call from the worksheet directly.